# Matplotlib won't install properly on Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've just installed Python 3.5 to experience its functionality. The problem is that all the modules I use in my daily programming have been installed and run very well on it except Matplotlib. I installed it via `pip` and never faced any errors while installing, but when I wanted to import it, the error saying, `DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.` popped up.

What's the matter with Python 3.5, or Matplotlib?

Comment: You're on windows, correct?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, I'm using windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall the module using `pip uninstall matplotlib` then install it again using http://matplotlib.org/downloads.html

Obtain the .exe file that best fits your machine, in my case it would be *matplotlib-1.4.3.win-amd64-py3.4.exe*. This will be a more complete version of matplotlib for windows rather than using pip.

I would also consider rolling back to Python 3.4 unless you absolutely need 3.5. There shouldn't be a compatibility issue between 3.4 and 3.5 for Python, but as far as matplotlib it's been tested with 3.4, but if you run through problems on 3.5 I would roll back.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python 3.5 you should install MS's Redistributable DLLs to make matplotlib working on Windows... In my case, no need to reinstall matplotlib even...

Try this [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html) without. If error appears install [that](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) and try with it (you must log in MS site and download version for arch you using - i tested x86 only, Windows 7, Python 3.5).

That case is included in [matplotlib install documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html)!

Remember, you should always read documentation before you ask!