# Can't embed graph into tkinter

Tags: python, debugging, matplotlib, tkinter, module

I am trying to embed a graph into a tkinter window. The import code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
# implement the default mpl key bindings
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler


from matplotlib.figure import Figure
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Álvaro/Desktop/Mates/codi/matplotlib.practica/insertar_graf_tkinter.py", line 5, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
  File "C:\Users\Álvaro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 13, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg
  File "C:\Users\Álvaro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\tkagg.py", line 9, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends import _tkagg
ImportError: DLL load failed:  The specified module could not be found.
```

I use Python 3.5.1 on Windows 8. The matplotlib module was installed via pip.

Comment: I think you should check if `Tk` is available. Try `import Tkinter` alone and see if this throws an error.

Comment: I've checked that and no error has been thrown. I've used 'import tkinter' since I use python 3.

Comment: In that case my guess would be that you have a non-matching matplotlib version installed.

Answer (score 0):

I did what the second answer by @Volodia to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767491/matplotlib-wont-install-properly-on-python-3-5) question said and worked fine. Problem solved.